# Find sum of $n$ consecutive sets of numbers is less than $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

```
row label | Value ni(n sub i)
______________________
1.        | 3
2.        | 7
3.        | 9
4.        | 12
5.        | 13
6.        | 17
7.        | 119
8.        | 12
9.        | 90
10.       | 12
11.       | 113
12.       | 17
13.       | 119
14.       | 4
```

...and so on till **L** rows. n<sub>i</sub> contains random values of the set of natural numbers. If the total length of the above table is **L(L >=2)**.
Given n<sub>i</sub> ∈ ℕ, is there a mathematical way to find
$$\min( \sum_{m=i}^{i+v-1} n_m )$$

where,
$$1 < v < L ∈ ℕ$$
$$i ∈ [1, L-v+1]$$

say, for $v=3,L=5$ this expands to
$i < 5-3=2$
$$\min( \sum_{m=1}^3 n_m , \sum_{m=2}^4 n_m, \sum_{m=3}^5 n_m) $$
from above table
$$\min( 3+7+9 , 7+9+12, 9+12+13) = 19$$

So, basically what this statement accomplishes to find is if there exists a sum of $k$ consecutive rows, whose sum is less than $H$. $k=L-1$ evaluates to finding values upper bound by $L$.

Programmatically, we could find that, but, I am wondering if there is a mathematical formula that could be simply derived or a mathematical model pertaining to this way of addition exists to give us a value (or atleast a boolean result, e.g. $\min(...) < H ∈ ℕ$).

Comment: "And so on." What is that sequence?

Comment: random values, will write that information, thanks

Comment: I mean, there is an algorithm that is $O(L).$ You won't so much better than that. If $S_{i}=\sum_{m=i}^{i+v-1}n_m$ then you can compute $S_1$ and then use $S_{i+1}=S_i+n_{i+v}-n_i$ to compute the rest of the values in turn. Indeed, this will be less than $2L$ sums to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple algorithm which is $O(L)$ time.

Let $S_i=\sum_{m=i}^{v+i-1} n_m.$ You are seeking the m8nimum value for $S_i.$

We have the recurrence $S_{i+1}=S_i+n_{v+i}-n_i.$

Compute $S_1,$ which requires $v-1$ sums. Set it to the current minimum.

Compute $S_2,$ which requires $2$ sums via the recurrence. If $S_2$ is less than the current minimum, then reset the current minimum to $S_2.$

Repeat for each $S_i.$

The total sums will be $v-1+2(L-v)=2L-v-1<2L.$ There will also be $L-v$ comparisons.